# Determine the mean of the product of the first two arrival times?

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-process

Let {X(t) : t ≥ 0} be a Poisson process with rate λ

Suppose it is known that X(1) = 2. Determine the mean of S1S2, the product
of the first two arrival times.

I am not sure what to do with the first bit of information, that X(1)=2. I figure that the arrival time would be ~ Exp(λ) hence I am thinking that

E[S1*S2]
= E[(S2-S1)*S1 + S1^2]
= E[S2-S1] * E[S1] + E[S1^2]
= λ(2λ+1)

But this does not make use of that bit of information. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that $X(1)=2$ means that there are two arrivals within the first unit time, so that $S_1, S_2 \in [0,1]$.

The problem with your answer is that you are taking expectation over *all* possibly values of $S_1$ and $S_2$ instead of just in the interval $[0,1]$.

What I am trying to say is that, for example, $\Bbb P(S_1S_2>1)=0$, yet you have (implicitly) included it as a positive value in your expectation.

So what we should do is to figure out the probability (density) that $S_1$ take a particular value GIVEN that $X(1)=2$.

$$f_{S_1|X(1)=2}(s)=f_{S_1|S_1 \in [0,1]}(s)=\frac{f_{S_1}(s)}{\Bbb P(S_1 \in [0,1])}=\frac{\lambda e^{-\lambda s}}{\int_0^1 \lambda e^{-\lambda s}ds}=\frac{\lambda e^{-\lambda s}}{1-e^{-\lambda}}$$

And we know that the inter-arrival times are iid, so we also have

$$f_{S_2-S_1|X(1)=2}(s)=\frac{\lambda e^{-\lambda s}}{1-e^{-\lambda}}$$

Hence

\begin{align}
\Bbb E [S_1S_2] & = \Bbb E[S_2-S_1] \cdot \Bbb E[S_1]+\Bbb E[S_1^2] \\
& = \biggl(\int_0^1 sf_{S_2-S_1|X(1)=2}(s)ds \bigg)\bigg(\int_0^1 sf_{S_1|X(1)=2}(s)ds \bigg) + \bigg(\int_0^1 s^2f_{S_1|X(1)=2}(s)ds\bigg) \\
& = \biggl(\int_0^1 s\frac{\lambda e^{-\lambda s}}{1-e^{-\lambda}}ds \bigg)\bigg(\int_0^1 s\frac{\lambda e^{-\lambda s}}{1-e^{-\lambda}}ds \bigg) + \bigg(\int_0^1 s^2\frac{\lambda e^{-\lambda s}}{1-e^{-\lambda}}ds\bigg) \\
& = \cdots
\end{align}

Comment: I think your answer is correct, but I have a question: your answer depends to $\lambda$ right?. My question is because this problem is from "An introduction to stochastic modelins", by Karlyn & Taylor and in the book the answer doesn't depend of $\lambda$. In fact the answer is $\frac{1}{4}$.